# Reduce Service Fabric backup size

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I'm trying to use Service Fabric backups with Actors:

```
var backupDescription = new BackupDescription(BackupOption.Full, BackupCallbackAsync);

await BackupAsync(backupDescription, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), cancellationToken);
```

But I've noticed that one backup file may contains several files like:

- edb0000036A.log 5120 KB
- edb0000036B.log 5120 KB
- edb00000366.log 5120 KB
- ...

I haven't found any info about these files but it seems that they are just logs and I may not include them. Am I right or these files must be included in backup?

These files are quite heavy so I'm trying to reduce size of backups

**UPDATE 1:**
I have tried to use incremental backup. But it seems that Actors do not support Incremental backup as I have read on MSDN. Moreover I have tested but got Exception "Invalid backup option. Parameter name: option"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing full backups every hour, you can also use incremental backups, which will result in a smaller size. (For example, do a full backup every day, and incrementals every hour for instance)

The log files are transaction logs, they are not optional for restore. More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-backup-restore/).

Comment: I have tried to use incremental backup. But it seems that Actors do not support Incremental backup as I have read on MSDN. Moreover I have tested but got Exception "Invalid backup option. Parameter name: option".